# Mobile phones keep disconnecting from pc

Tags: android, windows-7, appium, samsung-mobile, mtp

I'm running tests via Appium on mobile phones(Galaxy s5 and Note5).
I'm experiencing a strange behavior. the phone connected and everyhting works perfectly and I can even run tests, but after about 3-4 minutes, the phones are being disconnected and reconnecting againg. and so forth. It happens both on Galaxy s5 and 3 different Note 5. Actually I already tried to change the ADB cable as well and on two different PCs in addition to a Laptop, but nothing helped.
I'm afariad its all about the organization I'm working for. it's a big organization , but the Information Security Department keep saying that the USB ports on our PCs are open for free use and has no limits. anything else you could think about?